# Same Wifi network but different speed on two computers?

Tags: ieee-802.11, network-access

I just installed a new Wifi and was testing the speeds on my computers, a Mac Book Air and a PC. Surprisingly, the Mac gives me a much higher speed in seedtest.net!

How can this be possible?

Comment: NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Your question falls outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The speed (data rate) of your wireless connection is negotiated between the access point and the individual client, based primarily on signal to noise ratio (SNR).  It can be (and often is) different for different devices on the same access point.

The factors that affect SNR are distance from the access point, obstructions, antenna orientation, and transmitter power, to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

to add some more info to @Ron's answer-

Different clients may use different hardware and software, so even if you place both of them in an isolated and controlled environment you might still get different results.

It's even more complicated in reality since for example if you put your iPhone near your Mac they will communicate with each other creating some disturbances, while this will not happen with a Windows machine.

Hardware is everything from the controller itself, controller peripherals (power amplifiers etc.), antenna design and location, integration of all of the above with cables, conductors or connectors for example. Note that this might be different for the transmit and receive path.

Each part of the chain can influence the chosen final speed, first by adding a different attenuation but also by small implementation details. An imaginary example could be the choice and design of the D/A and A/D stage.

Than there's the software the runs all this, it's the MAC layer but also the higher level driver and lower layer firmware. All have different implementations per platform and hardware.

Unrelated to WIFI since you measure performance using a web site then even the IP stack, the OS itself and browser can influence your results.

Last and not necessarily least are bugs found all over the above, bugs in software but also bugs in hardware.